# Quering with Python Connector with variables

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

i am new in python and i have a simple issue that i cannot resolve.
I am in windows platform and unfortunately i cannot change this cause of work. I have to connect to many mysql tables and do sort of things with the extracted data. The code that i have:

```
conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host='<ip>',user='<user>',\
       password='',database='<my database>')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute ("select field from TABLE")

results = c.fetchall()


for row in results:
    c.execute("select * from otherTable where nodo = %s",(str(row[0])))
    if c.rowcount == 0:
        doSomething()
    else:
        doOtherThing()

c.close()
```

when I run this with Python34 i got the error:

"you have an error in your sql synthax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right synthax to use near '%s' at line 1

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to put single quotes around your %s like this: `c.execute("select * from otherTable where nodo = '%s'",(str(row[0])))`

you should also consider putting your query in a variable and then executing it like so:

`query = ("select * from otherTable where nodo = '%s'",(str(row[0])))`

`c.execute(query)`

This way helps prevents potential sql injection attacks and allows you to do a `print(query)` so you can debug the sql statement if you are getting errors.

Comment: operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset) Attribute Error: 'Tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I am not sure where the script is bombing out based on that error and your code above...can you put some print statements in your script and see where it is bombing out?? You have to be able to debug if you are going to write any code...